# Toast not showing on my project

Tags: android, toast

Ok to test the toast I simply put this on my Oncreate method:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

It don't show anything nor errors at all. BUT if I create a new blank project it works.

Comment: @Newbee : try to use current component context instead of `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: You are passing wrong Context, use getApplicationContext() only if you know what are you doing. Pass `this` instead

Comment: use activityName.this instead of getApplicationContext()

Comment: I wonder if the downvoters know what they are downvoting for?

Comment: obviously question is off-topic: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.* .... what can i say about this code:  **it works for me**

Comment: Well considering 3 people were able to answer this within a couple of minutes I would say it's got enough info in the question to be answered. If also includes desired behavior, and OP states that there are no errors to report, and that OP has tried to debug by testing with a new blank project. How would you suggest the question could be improved to be valid in this scenario?

Comment: to answer? huh? toast works with application context like a charm ... of course if it is not null and "in right lifecycle's cycle" ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a new blank project and copy all the files in it. I guess the problem was produced by the automatic-created action bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this way because of this its set only one time in globle class and use any where.
make this method in your globle class.

```
public static void ShowTost(Context context, String ToastMessage) {
    Toast.makeText(context, ToastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and use in any activity.

```
CommanClass com;
com.ShowTost(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.login_succes));
```

its simply to set this.

Comment: @Newbee its not and issues use this in next project.

Answer (score 0):

Their might be problem with the context you are using. Try this:

```
getActivity(),getContext(),getBaseContext().
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do a clean build?

Also instead of

```
getApplicationContext
```

try

```
Toast.makeText(myActivity.this,"My Toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```